# NullPointerException in JXImageView

Tags: java, swingx

I'm having a problem with the following code.It's throwing a NullPointerException.

```
    private org.jdesktop.swingx.JXImageView Logo;
    public Login(){
    try{
        Logo.setImageString("logo_medical.jpg");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    initComponents();
}
```

The picture "log_medical.jpg" is included int the src folder of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is the intialization??

```
 private org.jdesktop.swingx.JXImageView Logo  =  ???
```

with out that you are trying to use it

```
 Logo.setImageString("logo_medical.jpg"); //here Logo is null
```

You should instantiate in order to use it

```
private org.jdesktop.swingx.JXImageView Logo  = new JXImageView();
```

**And Follow java naming conventions**

`Logo` should be `logo`

Answer (score 0):

Logo is not initialized, it is set to null. Not sure what init is doing but you may have to put it before anything else, try this:

```
   private org.jdesktop.swingx.JXImageView Logo;
    public Login(){
    initComponents();
    try{
        Logo.setImageString("logo_medical.jpg");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private org.jdesktop.swingx.JXImageView Logo;
```

is just a reference.You need to instantiate Logo variable.

```
private org.jdesktop.swingx.JXImageView Logo = new org.jdesktop.swingx.JXImageView();
```